# (MVC5) Ajax.ActionLink not opening in popup

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Ok so the Ajax.ActionLink doesn't open the popup.

My _Layout.cshtml contains:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My Index.cshtml:

```
  @Ajax.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "result", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "openPopup" })

    <div id="result" style="display:none;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#result").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Title',
                width: 500,
                height: 'auto',
                modal: true
            });
        });
        function openPopup() {
            $("#result").dialog("open");
        }
    </script>
```

And my controller:

```
  public PartialViewResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return PartialView();
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged? Is the controller hit? Is showPopup hit?

Comment: did you try HttpMethod = "POST"?